# Batch Script Removing characters from a variable inside a FOR loop

Tags: variables, for-loop, expand, batch-file

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%A IN (*.*) DO (
 SET var=%%A
 ECHO !var:~0,-4!
)
```

Since we're iterating the variable within the FOR loop, you have to use `!` around the variable, however, in conjunction with the method `:~#,-#` to remove characters from the end of the variable, it doesn't take.

In my example, we are just removing the extension from the filename. I understand that you can use `%%~nA` to just get the filename, but this is just an example of usage.

Is there a way to do this inside of the FOR loop? Maybe a different method than what I am using?

Comment: The above example you posted works for me - that is, it takes away last 4 characters in file name (if there are more than 4 characters in filename).

Comment: This works for me no problem. I just copied this without changing anything, only added `@ECHO OFF` at the beginning. What particularly is wrong when you are running this script?

Comment: LOL i guess I fixed my own problem without even knowing it =/. Now if only I could figure out what I was doing wrong before XD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could fail if there are hidden spaces behind `set var=%%A`.
Then you only remove the spaces, therefore it's better to use

`set "var=%%A"`

It's independent of hidden spaces, even characers are ignored behind the last quote.

But perhaps your problem is of a completly different type?